# How to create on-premises RHEL server to docker image

Tags: docker

I have been working on private organization and there is restricted policy for downloading docker images. 
So I am planning to use default RHEL server to convert tar.gz and try to import on docker engine.

If anyone has the details please share for changing normal server to docker image.

Comment: Can you get approved to use the RHEL docker images?

Comment: This not implemented but how use, even ubuntu, centos etc...

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your own local Docker registry to allow pull from hosts without Internet.

Consider still basing your images on Docker Hub images or similar examples. A container environment is different from a full operating system with a kernel. Push images from a host with Internet.

Documentation suggests [crossing an air-gap is possible](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#considerations-for-air-gapped-registries). The usual consideration that you need a way to copy or migrate storage without an IP network applies.